# C - Create linked list with strings

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a linked list which stores student's information. The list includes one `char *` and two `int`, my problem arises when I try to initialize my `char *` with a string, as I get Seg Fault when I do so.

Things I've tried: using `strcpy` instead of `=` as well as dynamically allocating memory.

```
typedef struct Student{
    int age,id;
    char *name;
    struct Student *next;
}Student;

struct Student *head = NULL;
```

Create linked list function

```
Student *create (){
    char name[128];

    Student *newStudent = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    newStudent->name = malloc(sizeof(Student) + 1);
    newStudent->age = (rand() % (35 - 18 + 1)) + 18; // age range of student from 18-35 
    newStudent->id = rand() % 1000000 + 100000; // 6 digit id 

    scanf("%127s", name);
    strcpy(newStudent->name, name);

    newStudent->next = NULL;
    return newStudent;
}
```

insert function

```
Student *insert(Student *newStudent){
    Student *ptr = head;

    if (head == NULL)
        return newStudent;

    while (ptr->next != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = newStudent;
    return head;
}
```

Build function

```
Student *build(){
    int size;
    Student *newStudent = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));

    printf("Enter size of linked list: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        newStudent = create();
        head = insert(newStudent);
    }
    return head;
}
```

print and main function

```
void print(Student *head){
    for (Student *ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
        printf("Student info\nName: %s, ID: %d, age: %d\n", ptr->name, ptr->id, ptr->age);

    printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    srand(time(0));

    head = build();
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should not be using `union` for the name and age/id fields in this case. [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) will not store all three members separately. Instead it will store members **one at a time** in one location.  So when you set `u.age` you will erase `u.name` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *name; strlen(name);` is undefined behavior, and a segfault is a reasonable expectation.  Similarly for `char *name; scanf("%s", name);`

In both of those cases, `name` is uninitialized (so you can think of it as addressing nowhere.)  When you try to compute the length of the string at nowhere, you get an error.  Similarly when you try to use `scanf` to write some data to nowhere.  Perhaps you want:

```
char name[128]; scanf("%127s", name);
```

or similar.  Whatever you do, you need `name` to reference a valid memory location before you use it.  Whether you declare it as an array or declare it as a pointer and assign it an address with `malloc` doesn't really matter.  (Making it an array is often easier, since you don't need to worry about `free`ing it.)

Comment: I fixed my code, to include you're input and a comment about removing `union`, but I still get seg faults.

Comment: Now you have the same problem with `strcpy(newStudent->name, name);`  You have not initialized `newStudent->name`, so trying to copy data to that address is invalid.  Try another `malloc`, or `struct Student{ int age,id; char name[128]; struct Student *next; }`

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work after allocating `newStudent->name`.